# Как правильно: прополощите или прополосните?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте, на ярлычке детского шампуня увидела метод применения данного шампуня.   "Нанесите на влажные волосы и промассируйте до образования пены.  Тщательно **прополосните** водой."

Вызывает вопрос правильность употребления слова "**прополосните**". 
Мне кажется, что более корректно было бы написать "**прополощите**".  Тщательно прополощите водой.

Не подскажете, как правильно?

Answer (score 4):

Есть слово **прополоскать**, от которого повелительное наклонение - *прополощите*. А есть разговорный вариант глагола - **прополоснуть** с повелительным наклонением - *прополосните*. Данное слово уже зафиксировано в орфографическом словаре Лопатина, толковом Ефремовой и ряде других словарей. На сколько допустимо на этикетках писать слова разговорной лексики предмет отдельного обсуждения, но оба слова; и **прополощите**, и **прополосните** имеют право на жизнь.

[Ссылка](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_forms/57812/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)

Comment: В инструкции по применению разговорного варианта слова ПРОПОЛОЩИТЕ не должно быть однозначно. А в существовании такой формы никто не сомневается.

Comment: Согласен в том, что "не должно", но не уверен, что "однозначно". Инструкции должны быть прежде всего чёткими и однозначными, и если для этого нужна разговорная лексика, то лучше пусть будет она, чем непонятность. Здесь, "прополосните" скорей мешает пониманию, чем помогает, потому его употребление - ошибка. Но если разговорная речь инструкцию упростит, то я буду только за.

Comment: *Тщательно сполосните водой*

Вариант **прополосните** немного корявый. Не звучит.

Answer (score 2):

Вы абсолютно правы:  **прополощите**. К сожалению, на этикетках, ценниках и ярлычках ошибки встречаются всё чаще, а изменить ситуацию к лучшему призваны мы с вами.

ПРОПОЛОСКА́ТЬ, -ощу, -ощешь и (разг.) -аю, -аешь; **-ощи** и (разг.) -ай; -осканный; совер., что. 1. см. полоскать. 2. Провести какое-то время полоща. Всё утро прополоскала бельё.
dic.academic.ru › Толковый словарь Ожегова

Answer (score 0):

> Вызывает вопрос правильность употребления слова "прополосните". Мне кажется, что более корректно было бы написать "прополощите". Тщательно прополощите водой.

Судя по всему "Прополосните" - по мнению автора текста служит для передачи однократности действия. Сравните, например, *кричите* и *крикните*. Но для глаголов совершенного вида такая однократность обычно не в ходу.  Так что  действительно не вижу необходимости в данном случае использовать "пропослосните" вместо *прополощите* или *прополоскайте*. Но допускаю, что в каком-то другом контексте такая необходимость может появиться. Так, не совсем марсианской выглядит, например, пара *пропрыгайте* и *пропрыгните*.

Answer (score 0):

Меня в этой инструкции смущает не только "прополосните" (на этикетках чаще пишут "тщательно смойте водой), но и "промассируйте". Тоже не очень-то подходящее слово. В словарях такой вариант не нашла

Comment: >но и "промассируйте".   
А как иначе сказать? Хорошо хоть не "промассажируйте".